# Is my proof consider to be correct?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Problem: Let $a,b ∈ \mathbb N$, prove that at least one of the following $ab, a+b, a-b$ is evenly divisible by 3.

My solution:

**Case 1:** If $a_{mod}3=0 \text{ or } b_{mod}3=0$ then we can say that $a = 3k,\ ab=3kb$ which is evenly divisible by three

**Case 2:** If $a_{mod}3=b_{mod}3$ then $a=3k_1+a_{mod}3,\\b=3k_2+b_{mod}3,\\a-b=3k_1+a_{mod}-(3k_2+b_{mod}3)\\a-b=3k_1+a_{mod} -3k_2-b_{mod}3\\\text{since }a_{mod}3=b_{mod}3\\a-b=3k_1-3k_2\\a-b=3(k_1-k_2)$

in this case we are prove that $a-b$ is evenly divisible by three.

**Case 3:** If $a_{mod}3$ doesn't equal to $b_{mod}3$, if this stands for true, there are two combinations 
$a_{mod}3=1, b_{mod}3=2 \text{ and}\\a_{mod}3=2, b_{mod}3=1\\
\text{if this stands for true we can prove that } a+b \text{ is divisible by three}\\
a+b=3k_1+a_{mod}3+3k_2+b_{mod}3, \text{since } a_{mod}3+b_{mod}3=3\\
a+b=3k_1+3k_2+3\\
a+b=3\cdot(k_1+k_2+1)$ we proved for all cases.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: If $a$ and $b\not\equiv 0$ then $\,a,b\equiv 1$ or $-1$ so $\,a\equiv \pm b,\ $ where we use $\,-1\equiv 2\pmod 3\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

This proof looks correct to me, well done!

The one critique I would make is notational: $a_{mod}b$ is a notation that is extremely uncommon and one I would recommend avoiding. Bill Dubuque suggests that it represents the remainder left over when dividing $a$ by $b$ (I had assumed it meant the image of $a$ under the natural map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$) which is certainly something that you should explicitly spell out. Generally I would  recommend you avoid using remainders and just use modular arithmetic, writing `3 = 0 \pmod{b}` to produce $3=0\pmod{3}$ instead. An uncommon notation similar to the one you're employing would be $[3]_3=[0]_3$, though I would also discourage using this notation due to its rarity.

Comment: What do you mean by deeming $\ 3\bmod 3 = 0\ $ to be "technically incorrect"?

Comment: @BillDubuque Well, $3_{mod}3$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $0$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ which immediately means that for equality to hold it would have to be 'equals' in an uncommon sense (as they are not 'equal' in the usual sense) that requires algebra to describe properly. We then get more complicated situations like $5_{mod}3=0_{mod}2$. Certainly this doesn't hold, although the way the OP is using the notation makes it seems like it should (at least to my intuition).

Comment: But clearly the OP's mod denotes the binary operator which returns the integer remainder (not an equivalence class in $\Bbb Z/3),$ so your critique does not apply. But writing the mod operator as a subscript is certainly unusual.

Comment: @BillDubuque Huh, okay. I'll modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: Note $\ n\bmod 2\, =\, (n\bmod 10)\bmod 2\,$ means that we can compute the parity of a natural $n$ from the parity of its units digit, so expressions with mixed moduli can be fruitful. That said, I do agree with your edit that one should use congruences instead of binary mod operators in contexts like this, as I often emphasize in my answers.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque -- I pinged you in another thread; not sure if that works (I'm new here). If you got the message, please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct, but if you're allowed to use Fermat's little theorem, you could go like this :

If $a$ or $b$ are divisible by $3$ then it is obvious that $ab$ is divisible by $3$.

If neither $a$ or $b$ are divisible by $3$, then let's take a look at $(a-b)$ and $(a+b)$. Take their product : $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2 - b^2$ and rewrite it as : $(a^2-1) - (b^2-1)$.

By Fermat's LT, both $a^2-1$ and $b^2-1$ are divisible by $3$, so is their difference. This means that $(a-b)(a+b)$ is divisible by $3$. Therefore, either $a-b$ or $a+b$ is divisible by 3.